# Swift 4 - thread 1 is waiting for execution of thread 2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have this code:

```
func doSomethingFromJSON1() {
        print("1")
    }
    func doSomethingFromJSON2() {
        print("2")
    }
    func downloadImage() {
        print("3")
    }
    func waitingForNext() {
        print("4 - waiting")
    }
    func lastThread(){
        print("Last THREAD")
    }
    func finishFunction(){
        print("Finish")
    }
    func doItAll() {
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

        dispatchGroup.enter()
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            self.doSomethingFromJSON1()
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }

        dispatchGroup.enter()
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            self.doSomethingFromJSON2()
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }

        dispatchGroup.enter()
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            self.downloadImage()
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }

        dispatchGroup.enter()
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            self.waitingForNext()
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }

        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .global()) {
            self.finishFunction()
        }
    }
```

I would like the thread "waitingForNext" to wait until the "lastThread" thread is executed and only then it has been started.

After finishing all threads, I would like to start the function Function finish (as it is now).

How can you do it?

Comment: Yous semaphore instead of DispatchGroup

Comment: Visit for semaphore tutorial: https://medium.com/swiftly-swift/a-quick-look-at-semaphores-6b7b85233ddb

Comment: With dispatch group you can't wait your thread to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per apple official documentation:

> DispatchSemaphore provides an efficient implementation of a
>   traditional counting semaphore, which can be used to control access to
>   a resource across multiple execution contexts.
>
> You increment a semaphore count by calling the signal() method, and
>   decrement a semaphore count by calling the wait() method or one of its
>   variants that specifies a timeout.

Update your code by following code. This means execute next task when previous task will be completed.

```
func doItAll() {

    let semaPhore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)

    semaPhore.wait()
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        doSomethingFromJSON1()
        semaPhore.signal()
    }

    semaPhore.wait()
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        doSomethingFromJSON2()
        semaPhore.signal()
    }

    semaPhore.wait()
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        downloadImage()
        semaPhore.signal()
    }

    semaPhore.wait()
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        waitingForNext()
        semaPhore.signal()
    }
}
```